# I'm getting "<unknown>:0: error: could not load the swift standard library" on cygwin

Tags: swift, windows, cygwin

I get the following error message after running the instruction "swift hello.swift" on the cygwin command line:

:0: error: could not load the swift standard library

I also get the following error with the instruction "swift run hello.swift":

PATH_TO_CYGWIN_HOME/usr/bin/swift-run: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have also tested from the Windows command line, and I get the same errors. My machine has Windows 10 Pro.

I'm just trying to get myself familiar with Swift, so I installed the swift compiler for cygwin as per the instructions in the following link: https://swiftforwindows.github.io/news/2018/02/12/Swift-for-Windows-Cygwin-20180212/

hello.swift contains the following code:

```
import Swift

print("Hello World");
```

Is there a missing library that needs to be installed, or am I running the swift code incorrectly? Or perhaps I should add a folder to the %PATH% variable (I added every folder I deemed necessary).

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the examples from the linked page successfully? You must be able to run the 4 commands in the first example without any errors

Comment: Run the commands from the first example in a mintty bash session in your cygwin home folder.The `tar zxf` command will generate some error messages about unable to create symlinks. Ignore those. After setting the path, you should see swift.exe when you do `which swift`. Add the path setting to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I get the same errors with the example in the link.

Comment: I also ran the installation instructions again from a mintty session, and also set $PATH in .bash_profile and .bashrc, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Do you have DISPLAY set in environment? It should only be set when you have the X server running. `:0` is a common value for DISPLAY. IIRC the linked page says something about no graphics so that might be a clue to which libs it wants. Try `set DISPLAY=`.

Comment: I launched xwin, and set Display to :0.0 with the instructions: 

run xwin
set Display=:0.0

--- Same problem.

Comment: In the "Notice" section on the linked page it says "no GUI". I take that to mean there is no support for running under X. Try not starting the X server. This means that you will not be able to run any graphics in swift programs under cygwin. You may need a different port of swift, one that goes to native windows instead of cygwin. An alternative is to start Linux in a VM like  VBox.

Comment: I installed Swift for Windows application, and managed to compile and run some code, which serves my purpose for getting familiar with Swift. I was hoping I could do it through cygwin though. Using a VM would be a good idea, in case I run into other issues with cygwin. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Must set SDKROOT first.
Try these commands it works for me.

```
swiftc -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe $fileName -sdk %SDKROOT% -I %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift -L %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift/windows && $fileNameWithoutExt.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your cmd and direct the terminal to the Folder where your swift file exists if don't ,create a new one at any directory

```
swiftc -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe $fileName -sdk %SDKROOT% -I %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift -L %SDKROOT%/usr/lib/swift/windows && $fileNameWithoutExt.exe
```

Now Paste the above command in command prompt and replace `$fileName` with your swift file name

I worked for mee